# How do I configure nginx to serve my Sinatra app instead of default page?

Tags: nginx, sinatra, thin

I am trying to get a Sinatra app running on a Digital Ocean droplet.

I have started the Sinatra app running in `var/www/myapp.com`.

I have confirmed `thin` is running with `pgrep -l -f thin`.

When I navigate to `myapp.com`, the server presents the default "Welcome to nginx!" page.

I understand I need to configure a server block and place it in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`.

There are two files in this directory: `default` and `myapp.com`

`myapp.com` looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/myapp.com/;

        server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;

        location / {
                prox_pass http://myapp.com:4567;
        }
}
```

What additional steps do I need to take to server the sinatra site? Have I missed a step? Done anything wrong?

Comment: Did you create symlink of your config file in sites-enabled? If not, pls run: ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.com && nginx -s reload. It could help.

Answer (score 0):

Friend , you can delete all configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Go to your nginx.conf (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf and add the following code in conf :

```
include /nginx/conf.d/*;
```

now go to /etc/nginx/conf.d/

and create your new .conf with example name with `nano` :

```
nano example.conf
```

then write your conf :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/myapp.com/;

    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;

    location / {
            prox_pass http://myapp.com:4567;
    }
 }
```

and do `CTL+X` to save your config and `quit`
easy just do restart by `service nginx restart` or `systemctl restart nginx`

Your website should be probably online
and no need to have `/etc/nginx/sites-enable` config even